# Alternative of ElementAtOrDefault() in Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to run the following query but it says that ElementAt is not supported.

```
List<Road> rdExist = (from u in db.Roads where (u.GPScoordinates.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Latitude == lattitude1 && u.GPScoordinates.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Longitude == longitude1) && (u.GPScoordinates.ElementAtOrDefault(1).Latitude == lattitude2 && u.GPScoordinates.ElementAtOrDefault(1).Longitude == longitude2) select u).ToList();
```

Can anybody please suggest an alternative to this. I can't figure out any myself. FirstOrDefault works fine but it can't help me in this query.

Comment: How about `...Skip(n).FirstOrDefault()...` to replace `...ElementAtOrDefault(n)...`?

Comment: ``(u.GPScoordinates.FirstOrDefault()``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I need the 2nd one as well. FirstOrDefault only provides 1st one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Skip(n).FirstOrDefault()` in place of `ElementAtOrDefault(n)`. That basically means "get the first element after skipping `n` elements", which about the same as "get element at position `n`" where in the latter case `n` starts from `0` :

```
List<Road> rdExist = (from u in db.Roads 
                      where (u.GPScoordinates
                              .FirstOrDefault().Latitude == lattitude1 && 
                             u.GPScoordinates
                              .FirstOrDefault().Longitude == longitude1) && 
                            (u.GPScoordinates
                              .Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Latitude == lattitude2 && 
                             u.GPScoordinates
                              .Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Longitude == longitude2) 
                      select u).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) & [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):-

```
List<Road> rdExist = (from u in db.Roads where
  (u.GPScoordinates.FirstOrDefault().Latitude == lattitude1 &&
   u.GPScoordinates.FirstOrDefault().Longitude == longitude1) &&
  (u.GPScoordinates.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Latitude == lattitude2 &&
   u.GPScoordinates.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Longitude == longitude2) select u).ToList();
```

`ElementAtOrDefault` is not supported by LINQ-SQL. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx).

Also, please be careful while using this query as it may result in `Null reference exception` in case of default values. So, better check for nulls before retrieving values.

Comment: Is it essential that I'd get an exception in case of NULL value because it didn't gave me any despite of empty DB?

Comment: @Jadoon - Nope not with the complete result, I was talking about `FirstOrDefault` as it may result null but that is the case with `ElementAtOrDefault` too :)